# Freeform Pro: List form values for lists

Tags: solspace-freeform

So I want to be able to display a Freeform Field's value of the picklist on a freeform entries list. I created a field with a list using the "Value/Label Pair list" choice. I can show the label, the field response chosen but not the value I assigned that choice.

These 2 attempts just output the label for the item being selected, not the numerical value I assigned.

```
{freeform:value:will_this_request_be_useful_to_other_hmis_users}
{freeform:field:will_this_request_be_useful_to_other_hmis_users default_value=""}
```

I want to be able to see: LABEL Of Choice: Value Chosen (number). Not the Label of the question, the choice chosen and not the numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your after:

```
{freeform:field:FIELD_NAME}
    {freeform:data:value} - {freeform:data:label}
{/freeform:field:FIELD_NAME}
```

ref: https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/default-fieldtypes/#multi_select